# Angular2, PrimeNG. Lightbox with autoplay youtube video

Tags: angular, youtube, primeng

I've used the lighbox with a youtube video like on the example:
I wish that once the link is clicked it starts the video, I've added a few things to be able to do that.

```
<p-lightbox type="content" id="pl">
    <a class="group" href="#" (click)="playVideo()">
        Watch Video
    </a>
    <iframe id="video" width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/9bZkp7q19f0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen>    </iframe>
</p-lightbox>
```

And now the ts file:

```
videoSrc = "('#video')[0].src";
playVideo() {
    this.videoSrc += "&amp;autoplay=1";
}
```

I don't have any errors but it's not working...

Can you help me with the code please?

Answer (score 0):

so this fixed my problem in my html I have this code

```
div *ngIf="videoData">
    <ul>
      <li id="videoList" *ngFor="let videoData of videoDatas.SopVideo"><a (click)="playVideo(videoData)" href="javascript: void(0)">{{videoData.Name|extension}}</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div id="videoPlayer" [hidden]="hiddenVideo">
    <video width="800" id="video1" height="600" controls [src]="sopVideoUrl" [autoplay]="sopAutoPlay">
    </video>
```

when they click on the video they want to see I call the playvideo method and pass in all data about that video. I then bind the src and auto play to variables in my type script.

```
public sopVideoUrl: String;
public sopAutoPlay = false;
playVideo(id: Sop) {
    this.hiddenVideo = false;
    this.sopAutoPlay = true;

    this.deleteButton = false;
    this.strVideoName = id.Name;
    this.sopVideoUrl = `./dist/videos/${this.strVideoName}`;
```

this autoplays my video and gets the correct video that the user clicks on.